# Elasticsearch geospatial search, problems with index setup

Tags: elasticsearch, geospatial

I'm trying to search for documents previously added to an index, which has been configured to allow geospatial queries (or so I think).
My elasticsearch instance is hosted on qbox.io.

This is the code I wrote to create an index from the command line

```
curl -XPOST username:password@instance-id.qbox.io/events -d '{
    "settings" : {
        "number_of_shards" : 1
    },
    "mappings" : {
      "mygeopoints": {
        "properties": {
          "geopoint": {
            "type": "geo_point",
            "lat_lon" : true
          },
          "radius": {
            "type": "long"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }'
```

As I've understood it I should create a mapping between my `events` index and the type of search I want to perform on it.

This is the code I wrote to create test documents:

```
var elasticsearch = require('elasticsearch');
var client = new elasticsearch.Client({
  host: 'username:password@instance-id.qbox.io'
});

client.create({
  index: 'events',
  type: 'geo_point',
  body: {
    location: {
      lat: 51.507351,
      lon: -0.127758
    }
  }
}, console.log);
```

This is the code I wrote to search for a document given a radius

```
var elasticsearch = require('elasticsearch');
var client = new elasticsearch.Client({
  host: 'username:password@instance-id.qbox.io'
});

client.search({
  filtered: {
    query: {
      match_all: {}
    },
    filter: {
      geo_distance: {
        distance: '1km',
        location: {
          lat: 48.507351,
          lon: -0.127758
        }
      }
    }
  }
}, console.log);
```

My problem is that all documents for the `event` index always show up, so I am not successfully filtering with the geospatial query; do you spot any errors or do you have any guide I can follow to do this? I've searched and just found only bits of information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple issues in your code:

**Issue 1:** When you create your document in the second snippet, you're not using the correct mapping type and your body doesn't include the correct field name as declared in your mapping:

```
client.create({
  index: 'events',
  type: 'geo_point',     <-------- wrong type
  body: {
    location: {          <-------- wrong field name
      lat: 51.507351,
      lon: -0.127758
    }
  }
}, console.log);
```

Since in your mapping type, the type you're declaring is called `mygeopoints` and the `geo_point` field is called `geopoint`, your `create` call must use them properly like this:

```
client.create({
  index: 'events',
  type: 'mygeopoints',
  body: {
    geopoint: {
      lat: 51.507351,
      lon: -0.127758
    }
  }
}, console.log);
```

**Issue 2:** The parameter hash in your [search call](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/javascript-api/current/api-reference.html#api-search) is not correct as your query DSL needs to be assigned to the `body` parameter (similar to your `create` call) and it is also good practice to add an `index` parameter to focus your search on (see below)

**Issue 3:** Finally, in your query you're not using the proper field in your `geo_distance` filter, you have `location` instead of `geopoint`. Your query should look like this:

```
client.search({
  index: 'events',                <---- add index name
  body: {                         <---- add query in body parameter
    query:{
     filtered: {
       filter: {
         geo_distance: {
           distance: '1km',
           geopoint: {            <---- proper geo point field name
             lat: 48.507351,
             lon: -0.127758
           }
         }
       }
     }
    }
  }
}, console.log);
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, I will try this as soon as I get home!

Comment: I've tried this and I got the following error: https://gist.github.com/lazywithclass/099ef5ec61f870a07e56
If I remove the `filtered` attribute from the `body` of the query though I get the expected results, could you shed some light on this or point me in the right direction please?
Thanks for the help, much appreciated!

Comment: oops, my bad, I copy/pasted your query and forgot to enclose it in a `query`. Updated my answer above.